# How to generate equals() and hashcode() methods using wsimport in jaxws

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

The generated classes from my WSDL using `wsimport` are not having `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods. How can I customize and generate the client classes to get `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

I am not sure about using JAXB to achieve this.

In Axis2.0 generated stubs these methods are generated but not sure why such a basic thing is not available in JAXWS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the JAXB2 Basics Plugin to generate `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods:

- https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics
- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins

Comment: Thanks, I will check this with wsimport, meantime can you please give an example if you have one.

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway.. is it only these few days?

Answer (score 1):

More information on how it worked.
I have to add classpath to `jaxb2-commons` and without which wsimport runs without complaining but nothing happens! After adding the classpath as below

```
<path id="jaxb2-commons.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dir.toolchain}/noarch/jaxb2-basics-dist-0.6.0">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

the below wsimport worked as expected

```
<wsimport wsdl="@{dir-wsdl}/@{name-wsdl}"
          taskname="wsimport-@{service}"
          destdir="@{dest-dir}"
          sourcedestdir="@{source-dest-dir}"
          package="@{package}"
          keep="@{keep}"
          verbose="@{verbose}"
          xdebug="@{xdebug}"
          xnocompile="@{xnocompile}"
          target="2.1">
    <binding dir="@{dir-wsdl}" includes="bindings-wsdl-@{name-wsdl}.xml, bindings-schema-@{name-wsdl}.xml" />
    <xjcArg value="-Xequals" />
    <xjcArg value="-XhashCode" />
    <xjcArg value="-XtoString" />
    <!-- Generates per-package jaxb.index file which lists all of the schema-derived classes in this package.-->
    <xjcArg value="-Xjaxbindex" />
    <xjcArg value="-Xsetters" />
</wsimport>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you specified *how* you added the classpath to wsimport.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to generate hashcode() and equals() using wsimport in maven, check this answer on how to generate value constructors, but also includes the configuration for generating hashcode() and equals() too:

[How do I make wsimport generate constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880727/1279002)