# How to generate toString method with jaxb2?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, pom.xml, tostring

I would like to overload the toString methode from my wsdl.

In my pom.xml

1. I add that in the dependencies :

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
       <version>1.11.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. I added this plugin in the build/plugins

> Blockquote

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl/META-INF/wsdl/</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>FrameworkGedServiceMetier.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <args>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                        <version>1.11.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I build maven is successful but I don't have my method toString in the class.

[To inspirate me i use this documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/User+Guide)

Comment: The config is fine (you may want to update the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` though). The problem might be the WSDL compilation since with normal schemas it works fine.

Comment: My answer to this question, ["here, shall help you. Although it is customized answer  to run the WsImport using command line, but tells you the required jars the plugin need"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550756/programmatically-use-wsimport-with-jaxb-plugins-without-maven-or-ant/46645680#46645680)

Comment: I have to manually trigger a 'generate-source' build step; it does not happen automatically during build for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with that version. Please try:

```
<version>0.12.0</version>
```

(It looks like `1.11.1` was [published by mistake](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics).)